# how to decline xmpp group chat receiving invitation using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp

Here i've attached the code :

```
NSXMLElement *imessage = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
[imessage addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:[[xmppStream myJID]full]];
[imessage addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:roomName];

NSXMLElement *xelem = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"x" xmlns:XMPPMUCUserNamespace];

NSXMLElement *decline = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"decline"];
[decline addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:roomName];
NSXMLElement *reason = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"reason"];
[reason setStringValue:@"Sorry Dear, I can not join right now."];
[decline addChild:reason];

[xelem addChild:decline];

[imessage addChild:xelem];
```

Any one can solve [Whats my mistake].

Comment: welcome, please don't add images as code.

Comment: what is error you are getting?

Comment: I can't Reject group chat Receive invitation... That code not work

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246337/how-to-handle-decline-action-on-xmpp-framework-objective-c

Comment: Yes, but that represents decline from others . but i need to decline myself for ex: when you send invitation for group join to me but i need to reject.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've Found Answer for my Question:

Here is my code:

```
    NSXMLElement *decline = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"decline"];
    [decline addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"Sender JID"];
    if (reason)
    {
        [decline addChild:reason];
    }

    NSXMLElement *x = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"x" xmlns:XMPPMUCUserNamespace];
    [x addChild:decline];

    NSXMLElement *message = [XMPPMessage message];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:Roomname];
    [message addChild:x];

    [xmppStream sendElement:message];
```